# VBA VLookup does not return any results but I can call the values directly

Tags: excel, vba, formula, vlookup

I am not sure what is going on here with this VBA VLookup.

I can call the value from the cell directly. I can call any cell value inside of the range I defined from the other workbook. But when I try to apply it to a Application Vlookup it just does nothing....

```
Set report_ws = report_wb.Worksheets(1)
Set report_rng = report_ws.Range("B2:B" & last_row)
' last_row has been verify with Debug.Print

With inv_twcl_ws
    x = Trim(inv_twcl_ws.Cells(2, 1).Value)
    ' x has been verify with Debug.Print
    inv_twcl_ws.Cells(2, 7).Value = .Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, report_rng, 1, False)
    '.Cells(2, 7).Value = report_rng.Cells(2, 1) This works so why not the vlookup!!!
End With
```

I have also tried:

```
inv_twcl_ws.Cells(2, 7).Formula = .Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, report_rng, 1, False)
```

Per comments I have tried the below and still no luck:

```
.Cells(2, 7).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, report_rng, 1, False)
```

And:

```
inv_twcl_ws.Cells(2, 7).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, report_rng, 1, False)
```

I have also tried to use `IfError` to get something there if nothing is found.

```
.Cells(2, 7).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, report_rng, "Yes", True), "No")
```

Comment: Why are you linking `Application.WorksheetFunction` to the `With inv_twcl_ws`? I don't think you need that (does it even work?)  If you step through the macro with `F8`, what happens when you get to the `.Formula` line?

Comment: remove the `.` in front of `Application`  Application is not a part of worksheets.

Comment: I have tried without `*` in Application as well but I will try again.

Comment: Tried without the `*` and still no luck. It is not returning anything not even an error. Also if `*` is not part of worksheets then why does it come up with the auto fill after the worksheet?

Comment: If it does not work, then the value is not found in the lookup range.  By using the worksheetfunction as vba any error will stop the code.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok so the value is not showing up but I have also tried `IfError` in combination with `VLookup` see my updated question.

Comment: It never gets to the IfError as it fails on the Vlookup.  Remove the `.WorksheetFunction` and only type `Application.Vlookup`

Comment: And you changed your Vlookup, put it back to way it was.

Comment: @ScottCraner I got it working now with the `IfError` as well. I had to delete the `WorksheetFunction` portion... Thanks. I thought the `WorksheetFunction` was required as all the post I have read are using it.

Comment: I'm wondering why you use `VLookup` but return the same column? It is just the same as `inv_twcl_ws.Cells(2, 7).Value = x`. And it will crush when x is not found in the range.

Comment: @newacc2240 Its not the same. I am checking the value of one cell in one worksheet to the value of a range in another workbook altogether.

Comment: My opinion, if you want only to check the value exist or not, use `CountIf` is enough. It will never, or merely, give errors. Returns 0 for not found, and >0 for being found.

Comment: @newacc2240 thanks for the idea. I will stick with code that looks for the value like vlookup though. I may need to in the future return the found value instead of a simple yes/no.